# Applying a multivariate function to lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Suppose I have the lists, x, y, and z:

```
x = {-0.30, -0.16, 0.65}
y = {-0.28, -0.19, 0.23}
z = {-0.15, -0.11, 0.18}
```

Furthermore, I have defined the following function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x (y - z)
```

How can I apply the function to the lists?

Comment: Have you already tried evaluating `f[x, y, z]` to see what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
x = {-0.30, -0.16, 0.65};
y = {-0.28, -0.19, 0.23};
z = {-0.15, -0.11, 0.18};
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := x (y - z)
f /@ Transpose[{x, y, z}]
```

Comment: No particular advantage, it's just this is how I thought of doing it, and J.M. hadn't made his comment at that point. There are always lots of ways of doing things!

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
MapThread[f, {x, y, z}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
g[l_] := f[l[[1]], l[[2]], l[[3]]]
g[x]
(* 0.243 *)

Map[g[#] &, {x, y, z}]
(* {0.243, 0.1176, 0.0435} *)
```

The first answer is perhaps better, I'm still starting MMA.

Answer (score 3):

My two pennies. Since the OP wishes to apply a function, here is the code with `Apply` (shorthand `@@`):

```
x = {-0.30, -0.16, 0.65};
y = {-0.28, -0.19, 0.23};
z = {-0.15, -0.11, 0.18};
f[x_, y_, z_] := x (y - z)
```

Then, create input value sets. For many variables (datasets), there are plenty of easy ways to do it without writing it down like I have.

```
set = {x, y, z}
```

> {{-0.3, -0.16, 0.65}, {-0.28, -0.19, 0.23}, {-0.15, -0.11, 0.18}}

And `Apply` f over the values:

```
f @@ set
```

> {0.039, 0.0128, 0.0325}

Simple evaluation `f[x, y, z]` also yields the same result. To evaluate for a specific set of inputs, e.g. the second (-0.16, -0.19, -0.11), then a crude way is

```
MapAt[f, set, 2][[2]]
```